# Issue with number with decimal point value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a textbox which accepts "Percentage"value like below :

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" step="1" min="0" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,3})?$/" ng-model="$scope.taxPercentage">
```

When user enters "0.5202" then it works but when user enters `".5202"` then the value is "`undefined`".

Now, user wants this textbox to accept value like this :

```
.5202

.3412
```

Now what is happening is when I print :

```
console.log($scope.taxPercentage); //undefined
```

How do I make this textbox accept percentage values with decimal points like "0.5202, .5202" etc?

Comment: Try this regex `^(\d+)?(\.\d{1,4})?$`

Comment: @HassanImam Can you explain to me a little bit about your regex please?

Comment: `(\d+)?` this makes digits before `.` optional and `(\.\d{1,4})?` accepts 1 to 4 digits after decimal.

Comment: @HassanImam Thanks for the explanation but when I use your regex and enter value "12.10" then it truncates the 0 from the end and the final value is "12.1". Why it is like that?

Comment: The trailing zero is meaningless for decimal number. Is the same thing happening for other digits?

Comment: @HassanImam Oh no, not for other digits. Just for 0. Also, is there any impact of "step="1" of this property for input values like ".5202" ?

Comment: You should consider lowering step value, step value might impact when you try to change value using the arrow key.

Comment: @HassanImam Can you recommend what should be the appropriate step value for my textbox please?

Comment: You can use step size to be the least value you want to change when you press arrow key. You can use `.0001` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

This should do but there may also be a more readable regex than that

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" step="1" min="0" ng-pattern="^(\.[0-9]{1,3})|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,3})?$" ng-model="$scope.taxPercentage">
```

Comment: Its throwing parser error for this particular regex.